# Something wrong with a 30 vdc variable power supply design

Tags: power-supply, variable

Recently I have designed a variable 30 vdc output power supply
When I tried it on the breadboard it worked fine and gave me a maximum voltage around 29.8 vdc 
When I tried to design the PCB ( its my first PCB ever )
And it has a lot of mistakes I know 
But I don't know why but the maximum output voltage is just 20 vdc
And when I increase the potentiometer above that voltage 
The multimeter reads nothing (open loop I guess)
So what could be the problem ?
Is it one of the capacitor ? Is it damaged because of the heat applied by the soldering iron ?
Can I fix it ?
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Please use standard English grammar and punctuation; your post is very difficult to read.

Comment: Your PCB is not horrible, but I would cut the pins flush with the board, and then measure the conductance for each trace with a multimeter to check if it was etched through somewhere. Then check for shorts where the solder joints are close to each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check C4 is inserted with the correct polarity.

Check voltage on LM317 input is more than 30 volts.